# Angular 2,4,5+ Input Mask with Validation

Tags: angular, validation, input-mask

How to Validate and show validation message in Angular Template driven aproach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**step1:** Download **TextMask** directive from npm by command 
      `npm i angular2-text-mask --save`.

**step2:** Import and declare the downloaded directive to your component file or in a common module where this directive can be shared with all the project components.

**step3:** In the component.ts file write the mask pattern as an array.
For example:

```
public mobileNumberMask = ['(', /[0-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
```

example: masked value **(123)456-7890**.

**Step 4:** In the element add the directive attribute such as like, 
example:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
 <input type="text" id="mobileNumber" 
    class="form-control" name="mobileNumber"
    [ngClass]="{'errorMsg': ((mobileNumber.dirty || this.formOnSubmit) && 
    mobileNumber.invalid)}"
    [textMask]="{mask: mobileNumberMask, guide: true}"
    pattern="\(\d{3}\)\d{3}\-\d{4}"                                                
    [(ngModel)]="person.mobileNumber" placeholder="Enter mobile no"
    #mobileNumber="ngModel"
    required  >

 <div [ngClass]="{'errorMessage':!((mobileNumber.dirty || formOnSubmit) && 
   mobileNumber.invalid)}" >
       <span class="customMsg">{{'mobile number is required'}}</span>
 </div>
</div>
```